# buffer pool is destroyed on POJO type

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a custom source that emits an user-defined data type, BaseEvent.  The following code works fine when BaseEvent is not POJO.
But, when I changed it to POJO by adding a default constructor, I’m getting “Buffer Pool is destroyed” runtime exception on the Collect method.  I'm running Flink 1.7.0

```
        DataStream<BaseEvent> eventStream = see.addSource(new AgoraSource(configFile, instance));

        DataStream<Tuple4<String, Long, Double, String>> result_order = eventStream
                .filter(e -> e instanceof OrderEvent)
                .map(e -> (OrderEvent)e)
                .map(e -> new Tuple3<>(e.SecurityID, Long.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(e.OriginalQuantity))).returns(info_tuple3)
                .keyBy(e -> e.f0)
                .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
                .reduce((a, b) -> new Tuple3<>(a.f0, a.f1 + b.f1, a.f2 + b.f2))
                .map(e -> new Tuple4<>(e.f0, e.f1, e.f2, "Order")).returns(info_tuple4);
```

Comment: What's in your BaseEvent? Do you have the code for it?

Comment: Here's the code for the BaseEvent class:

Comment: figured it out.  it turns out that i have a field in the baseevent class that's initialized as Timestamp(Long.MIN_VALUE).  POJO Serializer can't handle it however it handles Long.MAX_VALUE properly.  Looks like a bug in Flink.

Comment: That's surprising. I can't find it mentioned anywhere in flink code or documentation.